# Выскакивает ошибка Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

столкнулся с такой проблемой: "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed".
Как вы видите, я проводил быстрые проверки, выводя в консоль метки о текущем состоянии программы:

checkpoint

false

we are in the loop

false

we are here

1231231231 потерял единичку своей еды, теперь у него 99 еды

Следуя из этого и репортам об ошибке это исключение выскакивает потому что после первого вызова result.next(), result закрывается.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
statement = connection.createStatement();
```

```
try {
                while (true) {
                        System.out.println("checkpoint");
                        System.out.println(statement.isClosed());
                        System.out.println("we are in the loop");
                        statement.executeUpdate("update users set is_dead = 1 where food = 1");
                        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select * from users where registration_time is not null && is_dead = 0");
                        System.out.println(result.isClosed());
                        while (result.next()) {
                            int food = result.getInt("food");
                            int id = result.getInt("id");
                            food -= 1;
                            System.out.println("we are here");
                            statement.executeUpdate("update users set food = '" + food + "' where id = " + id);
                            System.out.println(id + " потерял единичку своей еды, теперь у него " + food + " еды");
                        }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Остановка не удалась");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch(SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Следуя из этого и репортам об ошибке это исключение выскакивает потому что после первого вызова `result.next()`, `result` закрывается. - это исключено. 
`result` закроется если был вызван `statment.close` / `result.close`.

На какой строке вылетает ошибка?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но я уже решил проблему. Мне помогла другая статья. Ниже выложу свое решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что любое выполнение нового `SQL` через тот же объект `Statment` (т.е. любой `statement.execute...()`) закрывает предыдущий возвращённый `ResultSet`.

Цитата из документации по `Statment`:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
> at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
> interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
> by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
> interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
> open one exists.

В качестве решения для `statement.executeUpdate("update users set food = '" + food + "' where id = " + id);` вы, например, можете использовать другой объект `Statment`

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз нашел подобный ответ и исправил - все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код, который делает все то же самое, но без ошибок теперь

```
while (true) {
                        System.out.println("checkpoint");
                        System.out.println(foodStatement.isClosed());
                        System.out.println("we are in the loop");
                        foodStatement.executeUpdate("update users set is_dead = 1 where food = 0");
                        foodStatement.executeUpdate("update users set food = food - 1 where registration_time is not null && is_dead = 0");
                        System.out.println("все получилось");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Остановка не удалась");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```